# The jumps of a Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Poisson process with unit rate. Hence, $X_{t+h}-X_t$ is Poisson distributed with mean $h$. 
Then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_{t+1/n}-X_t| > .5) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_{t+1/n}-X_t > .5) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-e^{-1/n}) = \infty
\end{align*}

Hence, by Borel Cantelli's lemma
$$P(\limsup_{n\to \infty} X_{t+1/n} >X_t +.5) = 1$$
Does this mean that the time instances in which jumps occur, form a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$? I know that this can't be true, but I am not sure how to understand this.

Comment: This part of Borel-Cantelli's lemma requires that the events under consideration are *independent*, which is very far from being true here.

Comment: Ohh. Ok. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to compute the probability $$P(\limsup_{n\to \infty} X_{t+1/n} >X_t +.5) $$ in the above question. If so, what is its value?

Comment: It's zero because it is exactly the probability that a jump occurs at time $t$.

Comment: @saz: But then, it would imply that $P(\lim_{h\to 0}X_{t+h} = X_t)=1$, and hence $X$ is continuous at $t$ almost surely. But that isn't true.

Comment: no, it doesn't imply continuity since the exceptional set depends on t

Comment: Ohh. OK. Thanks a lot. You are awesome :)

Comment: You are welcome. (Just in case someone is interested in more details: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/739782/)